# How to form GET HTTP Request with IP Address

Tags: c, sockets, http, networking, http-get

When I use the below GET HTTP Request in C, I keep getting a `400 Bad Request` but it works when I use a string character IP Address (eg: www.wwe.com/index.php):

```
GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n
```

The %s after the GET is replaced with something like this: `http://54.236.192.188/index.php` and the Host value is provided by a hostent struct's h_name string value.

So a request looks like this:

```
GET http://54.236.192.188/index.php HTTP/1.0
Host: ec2-54-236-192-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand, can you please post how the request looks after you build it?

Comment: @iharob I've updated the code with what the GET request looks like after I pass in an IP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter for `GET` should be just the resource path by itself, and the `Host` header should be the domain/host of the machine that the request is being sent to, as specified by the original URL.

To request `http://www.wwe.com/index.php`, the `GET` request would look like this:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.wwe.com
...
```

To request `http://54.236.192.188/index.php`, the `GET` request would look like this:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 54.236.192.188
...
```

However, if the server runs multiple websites on the same IP address, you can't provide an IP address in the rquest.  The `Host` header tells the server which specific website to access.

Unless needed, `HTTP/1.1` should be used instead of `HTTP/1.0`.  For example, `Keep-Alive` isn't supported by `HTTP/1.0` by default.  And the `Host` header is required for HTTP 1.1.

Comment: It is valid to specify an absolute URL in the request line, when sending the request to an HTTP proxy for instance.

Comment: @RemyLebeau so is it valid to specify that URL with an IP address too? Like my problem description?

Comment: Where is the host value derived from? Should I be getting that from the hostent struct's h_name?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Only to a proxy, or in general to a webserver too? Didn't know that, I'll test it out some day.

Comment: @Vimzy: The `Host` header value comes from the host portion of the URL, not from a DNS lookup. Why are you using `hostent` at all?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm using it to gather information to fill in a sockaddr_in struct. So there are 2 problems here: 1. I cannot directly give the IP address when I run the request right? 2. The host header value should simply be derived from the passed in URL (www.wwe.com/index.php --> www.wwe.com) ?

Comment: @Danny_ds Only to a proxy. And of course, if you're connecting through a proxy you *must* specify the hostname so the proxy knows where to connect to.

Comment: @Vimzy: That is correct. Given the original URL, you simply pull out the hostname portion of it, resolve that to an IP for purposes of connecting a socket, and then split the URL into its host and path portions and put them in the different sections of the `GET` request, as shown above. If you are connecting to a proxy, you connect to the proxy IP and request the entire URL as-is, let the proxy resolve and connect to the host on its end and then request the resource for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Alright, it makes sense for character IP addresses. But how would I run the request if I pass in the IP address version of www.wwe.com like this: http://54.236.192.188/index.php <--- How would the GET HTTP request be formed for that? The Host would be: 54.236.192.188 right?

Comment: If all you have is an IP address, then either send an HTTP 1.0 request without a `Host` header at all, or else send an HTTP 1.1 request with the `Host` header set to the IP address. That is all you can do. If the server runs multiple sites on the same IP, it will reject an IP-only request since it won't know which site you are trying to access. That is why HTTP 1.1 added  the `Host` header in the first place, to allow IP sharing.